# Using The "Across" preposition in "The Pharmacy is across the Market" sentence is appropriate?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spoken-english

I wanted to ask if "across" can be used in daily life like that, or using "opposite" is a more proper one instead of "across"

Comment: It’s not clear what meaning you intend for your sentence, but in general *across* is used in the form “across *X* from *Y*.”  Thus, *Vancouver is across **the border** from **Seattle***.

Comment: The pharmacy is across **the plaza from** the Market. Can you use your phrasing casually? Sure, if your listener understands you.

Comment: Your title suggests a false choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could say '**The** pharmacy is across the market' to indicate that it is somewhere on the other side of the market place.

If you use *opposite* you need a point of reference. 'The pharmacy is on the other side, opposite the post office' (the two buildings directly face one another across the market place).

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou - I have made a comment - but that is not relevant to _this_ question!